# jQuery ul li slideUp / slideDown

Tags: jquery, slidedown, slideup

I'm trying to make 2 buttons for a list to slideUp and slideDown the list. slideUp works, it puts the first item after the last but slideDown doesn't work as it should.

HTML:

```
<button class="button" type="button">UP</button>
<ul id="ulLatestNews">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
    <li>Item 3</li>
    <li>Item 4</li>
    <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
<button class="button2" type="button">DOWN</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".button").click(function(){
      $("#ulLatestNews li:first").slideUp(200, function () { $(this).appendTo($("#ulLatestNews li:last")).slideDown(); });
  });
  $(".button2").click(function(){
      $("#ulLatestNews li:last").slideDown(200, function () { $(this).appendTo($("#ulLatestNews li:first")).slideUp(); });
  });
});
```

Here is the code on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2U9qZ

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to append and preapend the element into the UL itself, otherwise you'll add the element inside of another LI

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdragon/2U9qZ/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".button").click(function () {
        $("#ulLatestNews li:first").slideUp(200, function () {
            $(this).appendTo($("#ulLatestNews")).slideDown();
        });
    });
    $(".button2").click(function () {
        $("#ulLatestNews li:last").slideDown(200, function () {
            $(this).prependTo($("#ulLatestNews")).slideDown();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! Just a little question: why does the slideUp animate the list (slide effect) but slideDown doesn't? I would like to have the same non-effect for slideUp as slideDown, if it's possible, of course.

Comment: that's because you're slide down the list and the LI

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".button").click(function(){
     $("#ulLatestNews li:first").slideUp(200, function () {              
         $(this).appendTo($("#ulLatestNews li:last")).slideDown(); });
     });

     $(".button2").click(function(){
        $("#ulLatestNews li:last").slideDown(200, function () {        
           $(this).prependTo($("#ulLatestNews li:first")).slideDown(); 
       });
   });
});
```

Fixed fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2U9qZ/2/

Comment: Thanks for your reply but it's not working properly. If you press Down multiple times, Item 1 will stick to the bottom of the list.